# Error while getting count of a variable in linq using group by

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.2

I have a linq query to get count of number of tests. I am using group by and count but I am getting an error

```
    var response = from st in students
           join c in classes on st.id equals c.studentid
           join sd in subjectDetails on sd.classId equals c.id && sd.studentid equals c.studentid
           group st.id,st.Name,c.Class,sd.Tests into res
           select new StudentResponse
               {
                 StudentName = res.key.Name,
                 StudentClass = res.key.Class
                 StudentGrades = new List<StudentGrades> 
                 {
                    NumberOfTests = res.Count(x => x.Tests != ""), // I am getting an error here
                    Subject = res.Key.OperationName,
                    TotalMarks = res.Sum(x => x.ItemsCount)
                 }
                }).ToListAsync();
```

Error:

> Could not be translated and will be evaluated locally.'. This exception can be suppressed or logged by passing event ID 'RelationalEventId.QueryClientEvaluationWarning' to the 'ConfigureWarnings' method in 'DbContext.OnConfiguring

How can I get the count of number of tests which is in group by?

Comment: Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities

Comment: Is it a warning or an error?